# jQuery mouseenter and z-index not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

**The problem**

I have an HTML page with a navigation bar and a language menu. The language menu pops down on mouseenter.

However, depending on which one is defined in markup first, I get different effects.

**Note:** This is only a basic setup to show what the problem is. Style is not important right now.

**Scenario 1: Navigation first, language menu second (z-index and mouseenter problems)**

[image]

**Scenario 2: Language menu Menu first, navigation second (navigation breaks on mouseenter)**
[image]

**Minimal required code**

(Also here: http://jsfiddle.net/GEjjW/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html
            {
                background-color: gray;
            }
            body
            {
                width: 500px;
                background-color: white;
            }
            #menu
            {
                margin-top: 30px;
            }
            #menu ul li
            {
                display: inline;
            }
            #language
            {
                float: right;
                width: 130px;
                margin-top: -70px;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #language div:hover, #language div.hover
            {
                color: black;
                background-color: #ecfbef;
            }
            #language ul
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
                $('#language > div').mouseenter(function()
                {
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                    $(this).find('ul').slideDown(200);
                })
                .mouseleave(function()
                {
                    var div = $(this);
                    div.find('ul').slideUp(200);
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        div.removeClass('hover');
                    }, 200);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Menu #1</li>
                <li>Menu #2</li>
                <li>Menu #3</li>
                <li>Menu #4</li>
                <li>Menu #5</li>
                <li>Menu #6</li>
                <li>Menu #7</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="language">
            <div>
                <span>Lanugage: English</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>English</li>
                    <li>German</li>
                    <li>Spanish</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Question:** What can I do in order to make the language menu overlap the navigation bar properly without anything breaking or shining through other elements?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Certainly. http://jsfiddle.net/GEjjW/

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it up for you!  http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/GEjjW/3/

Comment: You split html, css and js up, but it's still overlapping.

Comment: I know, cleaned up jsfiddle, working on solution now.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the `z-index`... I don't see it anywhere in your CSS or JS

Comment: I did, but it's not changing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use `z-index`, you need to use `position`.  Make the following changes to your CSS:

```
#language div:hover, #language div.hover
        {
            color: black;
            background-color: #ecfbef;
            position:relative;
            z-index:10; /* choose number */
        }
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yQuxN/

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 #language
        {
            float: right;
            width: 130px;
            margin-top: -70px;
            padding: 10px;
            position:relative;
            z-index: 1
        }
```